# How can I pass different data(object array) by routing to same components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have two different "Clients[]" array inside my `dashboard.ts`.
How can I pass this data into 'ClientsListComponent'.

dashboard.html

```
<a routerLink="dashboard/my-clients" >My Clients</a>
<a routerLink="dashboard/all-clients">All Clients</a>
```

app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [ { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
        { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component: DashboardComponent},
        { path: 'dashboard/add-new-client', component: ClientFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]},
        { path: 'dashboard/all-clients', component: ClientsListComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]},
        { path: 'dashboard/my-clients', component: ClientsListComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]}
      ]
```

ClientsListComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'clients-list',
  templateUrl: './clients-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients-list.component.css']
})
export class ClientsListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() clients: Client[] = []; // I print this data on screen.
  @Input() title: '';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using queryParams you can pass the data

Sending

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
this.router.navigate([ '/your-route' ], { queryParams: { key: va1, keyN: valN } });
```

receiving

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  let value_1 = params['key'];
  let value_N = params['keyN'];
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it. The variable holding the array in your `dashboard.ts` can be exported, using the `export` keyword. Another component can then have access to the array using an `import` statement.

Another way is to use constructor arguments that get passed when the component is created, using the `@Input()` decorator in the component definition as you currently have.

In the template of the parent component, you can pass constructor arguments using the following syntax:

```
<myapp-clientslist 
    [arg1]="arg1" [arg2]="arg2">
</myapp-clientslist>
```

The string in the double quotes is evaluated as JavaScript. This, of course, requires that the variables are available to the parent component, either from having been received by another parent component the same way, through URL parameters, import statements, etc.